# Is it possible to run a workflow on all items using either workflow or plain javascript code?

Tags: workflow, document-library, javascript

Let say I have a forms library with a workflow (let's call it 'A') that is attached to it. I have configure that the workflow can be manually run.

So, is it possible to create another workflow (let's call it 'B') that when it run, it will run workflow 'A' for all the forms in the forms library? (or using plain javascript code to perform such operation?)

Are there also other alternatives such that when one press a button or run a workflow, it will run another workflow on all items in the forms library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect but could you set Workflow A to run on on item update and check if a column e.g. Workflow needs to run? = Yes. Edit the library in Datasheet view and change all the Workflow needs to run? to Yes. The workflow will run and have the last step in the workflow to change the Workflow needs to run? to No (default value). Then whenever you want the workflow to run you can just update the Workflow needs to run? column.

Either that or use an event receiver.

Here is a [link](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/09/how-to-start-workflow-programmatically.html) to a site explaining how to start a workflow programatically.

Comment: Hi Enilorac, is your solution for SharePoint 2010 or one that require using the Visual Studio?

Comment: Thw workflows can be set up using SharePoint Designer. I have never used an event receiver but I know they can be used for this kind of thing, I believe you will need Visual Studio to create an event receiver.

Comment: That would be a problem as I could not access the SharePoint Server. Any ways to use javascript or the default SharePoint workflow?

Comment: I know nothing about Javascript I'm afraid. As far as I know you couldn't use the default workflows for this, you'd need to create workflows in SharePoint Designer. You wouldn't need access to the server for this

Comment: From my understanding, if one need to use Visual Studio to do coding on SharePoint, one need to have access to the SharePoint Server. (For this case, it could mean that using Visual Studio to create an even receiver will require one to have Visual Studio installed at the SharePoint Server.) Also, to those workflows in SharePoint Designer 2007 are really very default (and also very basic as it could only perform limited actions on Lists and Library.) Unless the SharePoint designer that you are referring to is 2010 and the SharePoint Server 2010 too.